# SQL: How to convert integer column to date with yyyymm values in column name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have integer type column values like 202201,202202 till 202306(yyyymm). The column name is period_int and I want to cast it to date so that I get it in the format (01/01/2022) (mmddyyyy)

I tried datetime but it didn't work because I have the column name with values and not a single value. I have to take this value and represent it in the Tableau filter

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by first converting a string to a date using `to_date()`, then using `to_char()` to transform the converted date into the required format:

```
select to_char(to_date(period_int || 01, 'yyyymmdd'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
from mytable;
```

Answer (score -1):

See if this will help:

Convert the integer value to `varchar` and concatenate the result with `'01'` then convert it to date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), period_int) + '01', 112)
FROM <your table>
```

This will give you `2022-02-01`.

If you want the result to be dd/mm/yyyy Use it Like that:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), 202202) + '01', 112), 103);
```

[Check this link for more formats used to convert date to varchar or vice versa](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: It didn't work please suggest any other way

Comment: What did you get? error or what.

Answer (score -1):

this works for mysql but you should tag what DBMS you are using

```
select date_format(date(concat([date as integer],'01')),'%m/%d/%Y');
```

gives you

```
01/01/2022
```